# Spark streaming - join JavaDStream feed (textFileStream) with a reference data file

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

We are getting some text files every 1-minute and we aggregate it using Spark Streaming

```
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(60);
JavaDStream<String> file = ssc.textFileStream(inputDir)
```

However, upon aggregations are done we want to join the aggregated `JavaPairDStream<>` with another feed which is a reference data and arrives every 1-hour.

Is it possible in Spark Streaming to join 2 feeds arriving at different time-intervals?

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0):

You should persist the result of the aggregation of your first feed as a RDD on disk so the DStream could remove the batch data from memory and keep going.
When your other DStream starts a batch, you can join it with the RDD created previously.

See [Spark documentation on join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/streaming-programming-guide.html#stream-dataset-joins)

Answer (score 0):

We looked at Spark Documentation on the Stream-DatSet joins:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams

and figured out that there is a overloaded method in

```
<K2,V2> JavaPairDStream<K2,V2> transformToPair(Function<R,JavaPairRDD<K2,V2>> transformFunc)

<K2,V2> JavaPairDStream<K2,V2> transformToPair(Function2<R,Time,JavaPairRDD<K2,V2>> transformFunc)
```

which accepts the time param and it can actually refresh the dataset during each streaming interval.  This solved our  problem.